# jsTree dynamically change icon of nodes

Tags: jstree

Based on certain condition check, I have to change the icon of nodes in the tree.

Like: for below tree, where "M" is a icon.

Book
-- "M" book1 
-- "M" book2
-- "M" book3
-- "M" book4
-- "M" book5

lets say book1 and 5 condition is true, then its icon should change to "W" i.e inverted "M". rest nodes icon should be as it is.

Comment: Where do you keep that condition?

Comment: that condition will be in a java code and will be available json string.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

```
$("#YourJStree")
  .on('your_jstree_event.jstree', function(evt, data) {
    // your condition{
    data.instance.set_icon(data.node, 'http://jstree.com/tree-icon.png');}
    // your other condition{
    data.instance.set_icon(data.node, 'http://jstree.com/tree-icon.png');}
    //...
  })
```

See https://www.jstree.com/ for the different events.
Hope it help...